# Self hosted Kafka Connect Elasticsearch - SSL error

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Note: My environment is dockerized

I'm using Kafka connect with Elasticsearch sink plugin (extracted in the plugins folder)

My elasticsearch cluster is secured with **self signed SSL certificates**.

I have problems when configuring Kafka-connect to use my SSL secured elasticsearch cluster.

Connect configuration:

```
{
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "test",
        "key.ignore": true,
        "schema.ignore": true,
        "connection.url": "https://<ip>:9200",
        "connection.username": "<user>",
        "connection.password": "<password>",
        
        "elastic.security.protocol": "SSL",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location": "/certs/keystore.jks",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password": "<password>",
        "elastic.https.ssl.key.password": "<password>",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type": "JKS",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location": "/certs/truststore.jks",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password": "<password>",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type": "JKS",
        "elastic.https.ssl.protocol": "TLS",
        
        "batch.size": 100,
        "http.compression": true,
        "type.name": "_doc",
        "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
    }
}
```

To create the ***keystore.jks*** and ***truststore.jks*** i followed the official documentation https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/security.html
Even though the keystores are in the right location in the docker container (checked manually), it seems like the connector cant find or cant load them properly.

Anyone who had similar problems, i beg for guidance :D

Error stack:

```
[2022-07-27 09:08:42,456] ERROR Task elasticsearch-sink-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.indexExists(ElasticsearchWriter.java:251)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.createIndicesForTopics(ElasticsearchWriter.java:257)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.open(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.openPartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:509)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1000(WorkerSinkTask.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsAssigned(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:265)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1078)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:382)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:150)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:48)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.indexExists(ElasticsearchWriter.java:248)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 49 more
[2022-07-27 09:08:42,459] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
[2022-07-27 09:08:42,459] INFO Stopping ElasticsearchSinkTask. (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual SSL configuration pattern between any connector and KAFKA cluster.

### Worker.Properties

```
"javax.net.ssl.keyStore": "/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks",
"javax.net.ssl.trustStore": "/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks",
"javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword": "KeystorePassword",
"javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword": "KeystorePassword"
```

### Connector.Properties

```
CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SSL

CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks 
CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword
CONNECT_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks 
CONNECT_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword 
CONNECT_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword

CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SSL 
CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks 
CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword 
CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks 
CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword 
CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword

CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SSL 
CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks 
CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword 
CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/etc/kafka-connect/secrets/keystore.jks 
CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword 
CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=KeystorePassword
```

I am suspecting something to do with your Self-Signed certificates or mismatch between the certificates configured between connect and cluster.

If you have valid Certificate and if there are any issues during the handshake, this is the usual exception returned by the broker.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Unexpected handshake message: server_hello
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:304) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:473) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:990) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:977) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:924) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:430) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:514) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:368) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:291) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:173) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:563) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the quick response.
I use docker-compose and I mount the same volume with the certificates for both of the containers. Certificates are generated with elastic-certs-util, so I suspect the error is not in the certs.